# How can I get the other users' IP address on network with C#?

Tags: c#, network-programming

I want to get the IP address of devices which's are on my wireless network, and I want to detect when someone connects to the network.

How can handle network connection in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "you" are not the router (or whatever kind wireless dispatcher it is) there is no safe way for you to learn when someone connects to the network. Sure most OSes would broadcast their connection on the network and such, but it's not "mandatory" to do so. What I would suggest is to query all the possible IP addresses.

WAIT! Don't scream yet.

My guess is that you're aware of the wireless IP address range of the network, which I guess shouldn't be THAT big. If you do some kind of [ping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) on a timer on each IP address, you won't know exactly when the client connected, but you'll know he's there. This is true only if the router don't block the pings on the LAN and if the clients accept to respond to the ping.

Comment: hımm, I will try that, the real time when he connect is not important , especially If I use I can detect the time when he connect approximately. thanks.